# You can implement this step using the snippet(s) below?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have this feature file:

```
Feature: Agregar Cotizacion
  Scenario: Una vez dentro de SEITEM y pasar por el login, me dirijo a la sección de generar cotizaciones
    Given estoy dentro de SEITEM, voy a la sección de generar cotizaciones
```

and the implementation file like this:

```
package com.uva3;

public class CotizacionStepDefinitionsTest {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://seitem.loc");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("1");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='Ingresar']")).click();
    }

    @Test
    @Given("estoy dentro de SEITEM, voy a la sección de generar cotizaciones")
    public void irGenerarCotizacionTest() {
        driver.navigate().to("http://seitem.loc/agregarCotizacion.php");
        assertEquals("Cotizaciones", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void finalizarProceso() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

when it is running this happens:

```
Step undefined
You can implement this step using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("estoy dentro de SEITEM, voy a la sección de generar cotizaciones")
public void estoy_dentro_de_seitem_voy_a_la_sección_de_generar_cotizaciones() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}


Undefined scenarios:
file:///C:/Users/Juan%20Manuel%20Adarve%20C/IdeaProjects/standardTest/src/test/resources/cotizacion.feature:2 # Una vez dentro de SEITEM y pasar por el login, me dirijo a la sección de generar cotizaciones

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
1 Steps (1 undefined)
0m8,606s
```

how can i do that name of method not equals to **given** value?

I try change the **glue** in @CucumberOptions, but continue problem

Comment: I am no expert in Cucumber, but shouldn't he class be annotated with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` and possibly configure the glue, where then the methods with `@Given(...)`, `@When(...)`, `@Then(...)` reside? See [this `github.com` repository](https://github.com/turing85/spring-file-upload/tree/main/src/test) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

In the feature file if the line is:

```
Given estoy dentro de SEITEM, voy a la sección de generar cotizaciones
```

should always be implemented as:

```
@Test
@Given("estoy dentro de SEITEM, voy a la sección de generar cotizaciones")
public void estoy_dentro_de_seitem_voy_a_la_sección_de_generar_cotizaciones() {
    driver.navigate().to("http://seitem.loc/agregarCotizacion.php");
        assertEquals("Cotizaciones", driver.getTitle());
}
```